# background process in python with -e option on terminal

Tags: python, unix, subprocess, background-process

I want to write a console based wrapper to launch a program, and it works fine unless I try to run it using 'urxvt -e myscript' or some variant. For example:

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import subprocess

print 'Press enter to launch'
raw_input()

subprocess.Popen( ['firefox'] )
```

If i run this in a terminal with ./test.py, it works as expected. Firefox launches, the script exists. But if i try this with 'urxvt -e ./test.py' the script opens, runs, and firefox launches. But when the script exits firefox is killed.

How can I launch a program so its not killed when the script exits if I run the script using 'term -e script'.

Edit: To be more clear:
I want to launch a new terminal which runs the python script. The script does its thing and launches the program. Then the script exits, the terminal closes, and the program remains running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing this, I've found the results to be highly dependent on the program to be launched and the issue has nothing to do with python. I never noticed it, but 'term -e program' only works for some programs, others exit with the behavior I was getting. Some programs don't keep inherited pid/sid while others do.

For example

```
>>> print os.getpid()
3556
>>> os.execl( '/usr/bin/gvim', 'gvim' )
```

a quick 'ps -e' shows

```
3556 pts/1    00:00:00 gvim <defunct>
3557 ?        00:00:00 gvim
```

When the launching terminal closes, all processes with the same sid close. So the 'gvim defunct' disappears but the other persists. Programs which do not obtain a new pid/sid will quit when the launching terminal closes. The solution was to just force a new sid on the process.

```
import os

if os.fork():
    # parent
    do_stuff()

else:
    # child
    os.setsid()
    os.execl('prog', 'prog')
```

Answer (score 1):

add the ampersand symbol (&) to the command you launch.

```
subprocess.Popen( ['firefox &'] )
```

Comment: When using ['firefox &'], firefox still dies after script exits. So this didn't work for me.

Comment: This won't work. The subprocess will be killed when the parent process is killed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

print 'Press enter to launch'
raw_input()

if os.fork():
    # Parent
    print 'clean up'
    raw_input()

else:
    # Child
    os.execl('/usr/bin/firefox', 'firefox')
```

[os.execl](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.execl) replaces the python process with a firefox process.

As you noted, with subprocess.Popen, when the script ends, the firefox subprocess is killed.

With `os.execl`, the script does not end per se. It is replaced with the firefox process which does not end (immediately) (and is not killed). Once the `os.execl` command is reached, it behaves effectively as though you had called `term -e firefox`.

Comment: This is closer to what I want, but i realize I wasn't totally clear on the behavior I want. I've updated the op. With this, the terminal doesn't close after launching ff, and ff still exits when the term is killed. Also, I do need to do some cleanup after launching the program, so halting the script when program launches is a nogo.

Comment: @kalhartt: Hm. On Ubuntu 11.10, the terminal *does* close after launching ff, and ff does *not* exit. Anyway, since you need to do some cleanup *after* launching ff, I've added some code to show how to fork the original process, so you can launch ff in one process and clean up in another.

Comment: I'm running on archlinux, interesting that it has different behavior. Even this current example doesn't work for me. But forking was the right path, I just needed to add os.setsid() before os.execl and it works great! Thanks for everything.

Comment: @kalhartt: Oh! thanks for the feedback. Glad you found your answer. You might want to post it separately so others can find it easily and (like me) vote it up.

Comment: @kalhartt You could also use the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module and spawn an entirely separate process. That way the firefox process will continue to exist even when the python process that launched it exits.